# Good architecture for one if statement with many conditions

Tags: design-patterns, if-statement, architecture

I have an if statement which looks like this:

```
if conditionA() || conditionB() || conditionC() || conditionD() || conditionE() || condition()
  #do sth
end
#conditionX() methods return true/false
```

This looks ugly. Is there any design pattern which would simplify this?

*Language used: Ruby. Although I think a solution should be language-agnostic

Comment: try to give it a name and put it in a method.

Comment: @BigDaddy Ruby, keuleJ it is in a method

Comment: @keuleJ actually I didn't understand at first. You mean to do sth like: `def shouldDoSth
conditionA() || conditionB() || conditionC() || conditionD() || conditionE() || condition()`
end
and use it: `if shouldDoSth() #do sth; end`

Comment: Yes something like the answer that @Tanmay Patil gave...

Answer (score 4):

If there are too many conditions beyond maintainability, the best thing you can do is abstraction.

- Group the similar conditions by their functionality and name that functionality.
- Create `Boolean` returning methods for each group and call those in the `if` block.

Answer (score 2):

This is typically what `switch` (C, Java) or the `case` (Ruby) statements are for:

```
shouldAct = false
case 
  when <condition A>
    shouldAct = true
  when <condition B>
    shouldAct = true
  when <condition C>
    shouldAct = true
  else
    shouldAct = false
end
doSomething() if shouldAct
```

In Python there is a terse solution using a tuple of lambdas:

```
conditions = (
   lambda a : a == 1,
   lambda b : b == 2,
   lambda c : c == 3,
)
# evaluate each condition separately
a,b,c = 1,2,3
if any(map(lambda x, y : x(y), conditions, [a,b,c])):
   soSomething()
```

Note that each lambda is called with exactly one parameter here.

Comment: To my taste the switch makes it event more ugly :P

Comment: looking forward to seeing your proposal for less-ugly ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to tell without the full context.

One option you have is to inherit from a base class and have conditionA(), conditionB() and so on be implementations of a base condition() method. This has its advantages but it might not fit the example.

Another option would be to pass a condition() method as a parameter to the method that is using the condition itself. This option makes the assumption that there is a clever way to store the condition() methods to be fed to the method.

Answer (score 2):

In [Agile Programming: Design to Accommodate
Change](http://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/accChange.pdf), Dave Thomas recommends *decision tables*:

> Few developers are familiar with decision
>   tables—one of the simplest and
>   most powerful techniques for dealing
>   with complex logic. A decision table is
>   unique in that an end user can easily
>   specify and maintain it. The table comprises
>   a set of conditions placed above a
>   set of actions to perform (see Table 1).

They are certainly language agnostic, as they've been used since the early 1970s.