# one if statement with unknown number of conditions python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a list of list that contains all the conditions that the if statement has to satisfy, but the problem is that the number of conditions stored into the list of list is unknown. For e.g., the list of list is like this:

```
my_list: [["A", "0"], ["B", "1"], ["C", "2"]]
```

so the if should be:

```
if A==0 and B==1 and C==2:
      #do-something
else:
      pass
```

since I don't know the number of elements in the list of lists, **I cannot do**:

```
if my_list[0][0]==my_list[0][1] and my_list[1][0]==my_list[1][1] and my_list[2][0]==my_list[2][1]:
     #do-something
else:
      pass
```

how do I solve this problem?

A similar problem has been raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28477072/good-architecture-for-one-if-statement-with-many-conditions) but there is no a clear explanation/implementation of this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [*generator expression*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) within [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#all):

```
if all(i == j for i, j in my_list): # use int(j) if 'j' is string and 'i' is integer.
    # do something
```

Answer (score 2):

I think @Kasramwd provides the most pythonic solution, but an alternative makes use of Python's [`else` clause on a `for` loop](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html).

```
for item in my_list:
    if item[0] != item[1]:
        break
else:
    # do-something
```