# Prime numbers generator explanation?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, math, primes

I was searching for an algorithm to generate prime numbers. I found the following one done by Robert William Hanks. It is very efficient and better than the other algorithms but I can not understand the math behind it.

```
def primes(n):
    """ Returns  a list of primes < n """
    lis = [True] * n
    for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if lis[i]:
            lis[i*i::2*i]=[False]*int((n-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1)
    return [2] + [i for i in range(3,n,2) if lis[i]]
```

What is the relation between the array of `True`s values and the final prime numbers array?

Comment: Looks like it's using the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: That code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python/3035188#3035188) is basically a slightly optimized Sieve of Eratosthenes. Note that it's Python 2 code, it needs a couple of tweaks for use on Python 3. FWIW, I have a Python 3 version of RWH's code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38743446/4014959).

Comment: Walk through it with `n = 6`, write down (on paper) the value of `lis` and `i` as you go through the loop.

Comment: None of the answers in the suggested dupe target replicate Robert William Hanks' code exactly, although the general principle is explained there. Maybe RWH himself will see this question...

Comment: Algorithm fails if `n < 2`

Comment: BTW, using `//` is more efficient than using float division and converting the result. That is, `lis[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)//(2*i)+1)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with *n* `True` values in an array, with `i` enumerated from `3` to `sqrt(n)` by the step of `2`, if the *`i`*th entry in the array is still `True`, set to `False` all entries from `i^2` to the end of the array by the step of `2*i` (these all will be multiples of `i`).

All odd `True` entries above *1* that are left in the array in the end, are prime.

All thus found numbers, and *2*, are all the prime numbers that exist below *n*.